# BinaryFormatter vs SoapFormatter

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me why Objects serialized with SoapFormatter are more likely to successfully
traverse firewalls than BinaryFormatter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not talking about the difference between using binary remoting which needs to use a custom binary protocol, and SOAP which usually goes over HTTP? Generally firewalls are pretty good with HTTP, but you have to have permission to punch a hole through for something like remoting.

Comment: Also if the firewalls scan the content of the traffic, soap is recognizable and let thru, and binary is not and will be blocked.